# Ember.js: Add ClassBinding to outlet

Tags: ember.js

When using an outlet, it will wrap its content in a div, which in my case breaks my css.

So to get keep my html lean, I would like to do something like the following:

```
{{outlet "contentColumn" classBinding="controller.showDetail:col-md-4:col-md-12" }}
{{outlet "detailColumn" classBinding="controller.showDetail:col-md-8:hide" }}
```

Is there a way to:
- add classes to the outlet-wrapper-view?
- bind these classes using the bind-attr approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: 
First an outlet does NOT create a separate div. 
In my case I had an issue where my route.renderTemplate methods where not properly setup and pointing to inconsistent outlets.